# How do i check for duplicates in django sqlite database

Tags: python, django, api, django-models, django-views

I'm working on a django website for movie site, which uses an api to fetch relevant data about specific movies and saves them to django sqlite3 database. However it seems each time i refresh the page the request to the api gets sent again and the data keeps on adding itself to the database. How can i validate the parameters so anytime i make a request it checks if it exists in the database and if it does it just renders directly from the database?

This is the home view function

```
def home(request):
    query = request.GET.get("title")
    all_movies = None
    if query:
        name = request.GET['title']
        # url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=7531b4db&s='+name+'' 
        url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=73b26cd6e71f57e195d7a253e3911b74&language=en-US&query='+name+'&page=1&include_adult=false'
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()
        movies = data['results']
        poster_link = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500'


        for i in movies:
            movie_data = MovieClass(
                title = i['original_title'],
                year = i['release_date'],
                rating = i['vote_average'],
                poster = poster_link + str(i['poster_path']),
                description = i['overview']
            )
            movie_data.save()
            all_movies = MovieClass.objects.all().order_by('-id')
            all_movies = MovieClass.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)

    else:
        url_display = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=73b26cd6e71f57e195d7a253e3911b74&language=en-US&page=1&'
        response = requests.get(url_display)
        data = response.json()
        movies = data['results']
        poster_link = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500'


        for i in movies:
            movie_data = MovieClass(
                title = i['original_title'],
                year = i['release_date'],
                rating = i['vote_average'],
                poster = poster_link + str(i['poster_path']),
                description = i['overview']
            )
            movie_data.save()
            all_movies = MovieClass.objects.all().order_by('-id')


    context = {
    "all_movies" : all_movies,
}
   


    return render (request, 'main/index.html', context)
```

This is the model file

```
class MovieClass(models.Model):
    # fields for the movie table
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    poster = models.URLField(default=None, null=True)
    rating = models.FloatField(default=0)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    cast = models.CharField(max_length=800, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=5000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: make a api request if there is a POST request from the clientside.... or else just render the form that allows user to search for the movie

Comment: use get_or_create()..search on google about it.

Comment: Is there any way you could show me how to do it with the code above? As I'm quite confused as i don't have much experience working with django. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before saving try something like

```
if MovieClass.objects.get(title=i['original_title']).count() > 0:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have some bug somewhere and that the best approach here to avoid duplicates is to improve your model to include some constraints using [Model meta options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options) like `unique_together`. In the case of your model probably something like this will work:

```
class MovieClass(models.Model):
    # fields for the movie table
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    ....

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['title', 'year']]
```

Also note that `year` should be an `IntegerField`.